# XCode include path issue

Tags: xcode

So, I am new to XCode and facing the following issue:

Here's the steps I followed (Names changes for privacy reasons):

- Create a new Workspace "WORKSPACE"
- Create a new Project "PROJECT"
- Create a new Group called "group1"
- Created a nested Group within Group1 called "group2"
- group2 has classes A.h and A.cpp
- group1 has classes B.h and B.cpp

The next step is where I am struggling:

- For a variety of reasons, I want to include "A.h" in B.h file.
- When I do #include "A.h" it works; When I do "group2/A.h" or "group1/group2/A.h" it does not find it and compilation fails.

Why is that the case? How can I make it work like "group1/group2/A.h"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The groups in the Xcode project panel are *virtual* and have no bearing on the filesystem, which is what the path in the `#include` statement is interested in.

There is no reason why you cannot organise both the groups and filesystem to match, however just creating a group does not create a folder.

Comment: So, how do I create "real" folders in XCode?

Comment: @ajay When you create a new file you get to choose where to put it, including the ability to create a new folder.  You can then create the group for the new files.